# PL/SQL Get last line in file, avoid looping

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a simple oracle database and a logfile. Each row in the logfile is unique. There are a lot of lines (~1 Million).
I need to use the last line in the file as part of an insert statement.

Getting the file works fine:

```
F1 := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('USER_DIR','log.txt','R');
```

putting that inside a loop works as each row in the file is unique so i know if i have added the line yet or not:

```
loop
BEGIN
UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(F1,VX); 
-- do action
EXCEPTION WHEN No_Data_Found THEN EXIT; END
end loop;
```

But this seems **horribly** inefficient as i am going to read every line in the file even though i know i only care about the last line.

Something that avoided the loop and just went:

```
UTL_FILE.GET_LAST_LINE(F1,VX)
-- do action
```

Would be great. I'm sure there is a construct or something for this but i can't find it. It's Oracle11g if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

does this article help?

[UTL_FILE - Random Access of Files](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/utl_file-random-access-of-files-9i)

> The FGETATTR procedure allows us to check that the file exists and
>   return the file length. We then read the first line using the GET_LINE
>   procedure as normal. To get the last line we need to skip to the end
>   of the file using the FSEEK procedure and work backwards until we hit
>   a line terminator. The GET_LINE procedure does not return line
>   terminators so we detect it's presence by checking for the return of
>   an empty line. We can then display the last line.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
DECLARE
  l_file         UTL_FILE.file_type;
  l_location     VARCHAR2(100) := 'MY_DOCS';
  l_filename     VARCHAR2(100) := 'temp';
  l_exists       BOOLEAN;
  l_file_length  NUMBER;
  l_blocksize    NUMBER;
  l_text         VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  UTL_FILE.fgetattr(l_location, l_filename, l_exists, l_file_length, l_blocksize);

  IF l_exists THEN
    -- Open file.
    l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen(l_location, l_filename, 'r', 32767);

    -- Read and output first line.
    UTL_FILE.get_line(l_file, l_text, 32767);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('First Line: |' || l_text || '|');
    UTL_FILE.FSEEK (l_file, l_file_length-1);

    -- Step backwards through the file until we reach the start of the last line.
    FOR i IN REVERSE 0 .. l_file_length-2 LOOP
      UTL_FILE.FSEEK (l_file, NULL, -2);
      UTL_FILE.get_line(l_file, l_text, 1);
      EXIT WHEN l_text IS NULL;
    END LOOP;

    -- Read and output the last line.
    UTL_FILE.get_line(l_file, l_text, 32767);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Last Line : |' || l_text || '|');

    -- Close the file.
    UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Not quite as simple as i was hoping but it certainly works. Thanks